# calculate area of all polygons in shapefile in arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, area

I have shapefile containing lot of polygons, I want to know area of all of them together. Do you please know about some few clicks tool for my problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  A good question should show your own research and attempt.  Please **[edit]** your question to give details of what you've actually tried, and what was the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two ways to quickly do this. If you do not have area calculated in a field, create a new field called "AREA" with a float field type, right click "Calculate Geometry".

**Note:** If you do any editing on the polygons, you will have to re-run Calculate Geometry after. If you're using a geodatabase, the field will automatically update.

On your AREA field:

**Method 1**: you can right-click "Statistics" which will give you a histogram and basic statistics.

**Method 2:**  right click and use [Summary Statistics](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm). This will allow you to choose what statistic you want to calculate eg. SUM, MEAN, COUNT, etc. And it will output as a table.

Method 1 is the fastest to quickly get a sum. If you wanted a more detailed summary eg. Sum of all polygons by landuse classification, you'd want to use method 2.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new field in the shapefile's attribute table. Right click on the field. Choose to 'Calculate Geometry.'

If you want the total area, dissolve the polygons into 1 big polygon using the Dissolve tool. Calculate geometry.

Comment: If you want total area, right-click on the field (after calculate geometry) and choose Statistics.  Saves having to do a dissolve (and depending on how the dissolve is done, should come with a warning that the original polygons may be gone)

Comment: I would hesitate to use this method for two reasons: As @Midavalo said you could lose existing data 2) could be unnecessarily time intensive for large data sets when summary statistics/statistics are a right-click away.

Comment: Why would you lose existing data? Dissolve creates a new shapefile/feature. You'd have both. And saying it's "unnecessarily time intensive" assumes OP is processing thousands of polygons when in fact OP hasn't mentioned how many. If it's only like 20 then either way of doing this is fine. We haven't even touched on how a projection can also affect the area OP would calculate. This process has nuance and both our suggestions get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

**ArcGIS Pro**: Open attribute table >> Select all records (or any set you wish) >> Copy Selection (`Ctrl-Shift-C` or [Copy] button) >> Paste into Excel >> Format as table >> add Total row.

**ArcMap**: Open attribute table >> Select all records (or any set you wish) >> right-click on any row heading >> Copy Selection >> Paste into Excel >> Format as table >> add Total row.

[image: arcmap: r-click on any row heading to get 'Copy Selected' action]